# How to use zombie to test <input type="hidden">

Tags: javascript, html, mocha.js, zombie-process

This is my view, I want to test.

```
<h1>Request Group Rate</h1>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="referrer">
    Name: <input type="text" id="fieldName" name="name"><br>
    Group size: <input type="text" name="groupSize"><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     /* document.referrer: Returns the URI of the page that links to this page */
     $('input[name="referrer"]').val(document.referrer);
 });
</script>
```

I wrote my test like this:

```
var Browser = require('zombie'),
    assert = require('chai').assert;

var browser;

suite('Cross-Page Tests', function() {
    setup(function() {
         browser = new Browser();
    });


    test('requesting a group rate quote from the hood river tour page ' +
         'should populate the referrer field', function(done) {
             var referrer = 'http://localhost:3000/tours/hood-river';
             browser.visit(referrer, function() {
                 browser.clickLink('.requestGroupRate', function() {
                     browser.assert.input('form input[name="referrer"]', referrer);
                     done();
                 });
             });
         });
```

then, I run the test, I found the test will block at

```
browser.assert.input('form input[name="referrer"]', referrer);
```

(I annotate this line, and the test runs OK).

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "meadowlark",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A travel website",
  "main": "meadowlark.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/zwb-ict/meadowlark.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node"
  ],
  "author": "zwb.ict@gmail.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zwb-ict/meadowlark/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/zwb-ict/meadowlark",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-istanbul": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "istanbul": "^0.3.13",
    "mocha": "^2.2.4",
    "zombie": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
assert(browser.resources[0].request.headers._headers[0][1] === referrer);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer until https://github.com/assaf/zombie/pull/947 is pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you comparing the hidden element to the referrer variable correctly in the assert?

How about trying:

```
assert(browser.field('referrer').value === referrer)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the Zombile V3.1：may be good,but the lastest version is bad .
2. The Zombile master version have a bug,and also have been solved,but it have not been merge to the master version .So,we are waiting.

Here is the bug: [link](https://github.com/estevanmaito/zombie/commit/5584faa980efe5809312983dcbd6697088793d55)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
browser.assert.element("form input[name=referrer]", referrer);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.